# Poincare invariance of Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: string-theory, boundary-conditions, poincare-symmetry

The action which describes a string propagating in a $D$ dimensional spacetime, with given metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, is given by the [Polyakov action](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyakov_action)
$$S_{\text{p}}=-\frac{T}{2}\int \mathrm{d}\sigma\mathrm{d}\tau\sqrt{-h}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}\partial_{\beta}X^{\nu}g_{\mu\nu}\tag{1}$$
where the symbols have their usual meaning. It is not hard to check that action is invariant under [Poincare transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group)
$$\delta X^{\mu}(\sigma,\tau)=a^{\mu}_{~~~\nu}X^{\nu}(\sigma,\tau)+b^{\mu}\tag{2}.$$
When all the dust is settled (i.e. after gauge fixing and Weyl transformations) the Polyakov action becomes
$$S_{\text{P}}=\frac{T}{2}\int \mathrm{d}\sigma\mathrm{d}\tau \left((\dot{X})^{2}-(X')^{2}\right)\tag{3}$$
where $\dot{X}=\partial_{\tau}X^{\mu}$ and $X'=\partial_{\sigma}X^{\mu}$. Variation with respect to $X^{\mu}$ yields the equation of motion
$$(-\partial^{2}_{\tau}+\partial^{2}_{\sigma})X^{\mu}-T\int\mathrm{d}\tau\left[X'\delta X^{\mu}|_{\sigma=\pi}+X'\delta X^{\mu}|_{\sigma=0}\right]=0.\tag{4}$$
The $\sigma$ boundary terms tell us what type of strings we have, either closed or open strings.

- For open string equation (4) becomes
  $(-\partial^{2}_{\tau}+\partial^{2}_{\sigma})X^{\mu}=0$
  where we assume that the end points of the string follow the Neumann boundary conditions
  $$\partial_{\sigma}X^{\mu}(\tau,\sigma)=\partial_{\sigma}X^{\mu}(\tau,\sigma+n).\tag{5}$$
  One interesting feature is that **the Neumann boundary conditions remains invariant under global Poincare transformation** since 
  \begin{eqnarray} \partial_{\sigma}X'^{\mu}|_{\sigma=0,n} & = & \partial_{\sigma}\left(a^{\mu}_{~~~\nu}X^{\nu}(\sigma,\tau)+b^{\mu}\right)|_{\sigma=0,n} \\ & = & a^{\mu}_{~~~\nu}~\partial_{\sigma}X^{\nu}|_{\sigma=0,n}\\ & = & 0 \\ \end{eqnarray}
- Whereas the **Dirichlet boundary conditions** 
  $$X^{\mu}(\tau,\sigma=0)=X^{\mu}_{0}\qquad\qquad X^{\mu}(\tau,\sigma=n)=X^{\mu}_{n}$$
  **break the Poincare invariance,** as
  $$X'^{\mu}|_{\sigma=0,n}=\left(a^{\mu}_{~~~\nu}X^{\nu}(\sigma,\tau)+b^{\mu}\right)|_{\sigma=0,n}\neq X^{\mu}_{0,n}$$
  which simply means that under a Poincare transformation the ends of the string actually change.

> Does the spectrum of string excitations keep any signature
>   of this (non) invariance under Poincare transformations? If so, how can 
>   that result be interpreted?

Comment: v5: How did $\pi$ become $n$ in various places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dirichlet boundary condition, in particular, breaks spacetime translation invariance. This is reflected in the string spectrum, that is, a Goldstone boson state appears in the massless spectrum of the string. This state corresponds to the collective coordinate which parametrizes small oscillations of the Dirichlet 'brane' or D-brane on which the string is constrained to move on.

For the SUPER-string, a similar effect occurs whereby a Goldstino state appears in the massless spectrum, and this indicates the breaking of some amount of spacetime supersymmetry by the D-brane.

**References**: String Theory, Polchinski, Volume I (equation (8.6.18) and pages 268-269), Volume II (pages 138-140).

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious consequence of Poincare symmetry breaking is non-conservation of spacetime momentum. Of course, the string spectrum is also changed, and this change could be easily calculated.

Comment: It would be better, if you elaborate your answer using maths.